# Rails Uniqueness Validation - skip objects that meet a certain condition

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model that has three attributes including a state attribute:

```
RailsModel:
  attribute1
  attribute2
  state
```

I want to validate the uniqueness of a attribute1 on the scope of attribute2:

```
validate :attribute1, uniqueness: { scope: :attribute2 }
```

However, I do not want to check against any RailsModels where state = :canceled

Is there a simple way to add this condition or do I need to write a custom validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if conditional:

```
validate :attribute1, uniqueness: { scope: :attribute2 }, :if => "state == canceled"
```

There are many possibilities there, just check on [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation)!

Comment: My understanding of using a conditional like that is that any RailsModels where state == :canceled will not be checked for uniqueness. However, other RailsModels where state == :accepted will check for uniqueness **against** the RailsModel where state == :canceled. This is undesired behaviour. I want canceled RailsModels to be totally taken out of the equation.